# Two clause definition to find the maximum number on a list

Tags: prolog

How would I write a two clause recursive definition to find the maximum value in a list.   So far I have written this:

```
 max(L,M):-  

 max([H|T],M):-

max(T,H,M).
max([],M,M).
max([H|T],Y,M):-
   H =< Y,
   max(T,Y,M).
max([H|T],Y,M):-
   H > Y,
   max(T,H,M).
```

This doesn't work, it says there is a syntax error which I can't quite see, and I know it isn't two clause either. Anyone know how I could simplify it to make it two clause?

Comment: If this is homework, you should add the 'homework' tag to the question.

Comment: No this isn't homework, its just a basic difficulty I came across when trying to use prolog.

Answer (score 9):

As you, I use the 'max' name for the predicate. This implementation don't rely in any built-in predicate:

```
max([X],X).
max([X|Xs],X):- max(Xs,Y), X >=Y.
max([X|Xs],N):- max(Xs,N), N > X.
```

Comment: It will be more efficient if you add cut in the end of the first  line: max([X],X):-!.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax error results from the fact that the first two clauses have no body.

To answer your question, observe that the maximum of a list can be defined inductively as follows:

- The maximum of a list with one element is that element.
- The maximum of a list with multiple elements is the largest of the head and the maximum of the tail.

Thus,

```
max_list([H], H).
max_list([H|T], M2) :- 
  max_list(T, M),
  M2 is max(H, M).
```

This code uses `max/2` ([SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=max%2f2), [GNU-Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog029.html)). Note that most or all Prolog implementations will have a built-in function `max_list/2` ([S](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=max_list%2f2), [G](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc211)), so there is actually no need to define it yourself.

**Edit:** [Bakore notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816057/two-clause-definition-to-find-the-maximum-number-on-a-list/1816797#1816797) that a tail recursive implementation may be more efficient. You can do this by defining a predicate `max_list/3` which takes an additional argument `C`, namely the largest value seen so far.

```
max_list([H|T], M) :- max_list(T, H, M). 

max_list([], C, C).
max_list([H|T], C, M) :- C2 is max(C, H), max_list(T, C2, M).
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for max in lists of lists

```
max_list([], C, C).
max_list([H|T], C, M) :- C2 is max(C, H), max_list(T, C2, M).

max_list([], []).
max_list([[H|HB]|B],[RH|RB]) :- max_list(HB, H, RH), max_list(B, RB).

ex: max_list([[1,3,6], [6,3,8,2],[2,1,0]]).
```

Answer (score 1):

DOMAINS

```
num=INTEGER
list = num*
```

PREDICATES

```
nondeterm maxList(list,num)
```

CLAUSES

```
maxList([A],A).   
maxList([A|List],Max):- Max=A,maxList(List,Max1),A>=Max1.  
maxList([A|List],Max):- Max=Max1,
maxList(List,Max1),A< Max1.
```

GOAL

```
maxList([1,2,3,5,4],Max).
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works for sure

```
l:-listing.
m(L,X):-aku2(L,0,X).
aku2([],B,B).
aku2([G|O],Maks,C):-maks(Maks,G,Maks1),aku2(O,Maks1,C).
maks(A,B,C):-A>B, C is A.
maks(A,B,C):-A=<B, C is B.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below will solve the problem:

```
max_list([],0).
max_list([H],H).
max_list([H|T],M):- max_list(T,M1),M is max(H,M1).
```

Comment: What should `max_list([-1],M)` be? According to your definition: `M = 0` and `M = -1`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but here's an answer using the if-then-else construct:

```
maxmember([X],X).
maxmember([H|T],Max) :- maxmember(T, M),(H>M -> Max is H ; Max is M).
```

Answer (score 0):

max(0,[]).

max(R,[H|T]):-

```
max(Y,T),
H > Y,
R is H.
```

max(R,[H|T]):-

```
max(Y,T),
H =< Y,
R is Y.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
list([H],H).
list([H1,H2|T],X):-H1>H2,list([H1|T],X).
list([_|T],X):-list(T,X).
```

Goal: `list([3,9,4,5],M)`

Output: `M=9`