# N Largest elements of the list

Tags: list, prolog, repeat

I need to get N largest elements of the list.

I have predicate **largest**:

```
largest([X], X).
largest([X|T], K) :-
   largest(T, Y),
   K is max(X,Y).
```

Now I need new predicate **n_largest**, which works like this:

```
?- n_largest([1, 2, 12, 33, 4, 15, 6], 2, List).
```

**Expected result:** List: [33, 15].

I've made the trivial case of this predicate:

```
n_largest(List, 1, [X]) :- largest(List, X).
```

But I can't find out how to repeat **largest** for N times and make up expected list.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816057/two-clause-definition-to-find-the-maximum-number-on-a-list.

Comment: What would you like the result of `n_largest([1,4,1], 3, R).` to be?

Comment: @lurker it's a good question, I think it should also count duplicates. Just like you did in your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
n_largest(L, N, R) :-
    msort(L, LS),
    length(R, N),
    append(_, R, LS).
```

This will count duplicates. So:

```
| ?- n_largest([1,4,2,6,3,4,6], 3, L).

L = [4,6,6]

yes
```

If you want to choose unique elements, then you can use `sort`:

```
n_largest(L, N, R) :-
    sort(L, LS),
    length(R, N),
    append(_, R, LS).

| ?- n_largest([1,4,2,6,3,4,6], 3, L).

L = [3,4,6]

yes
```

Note that these predicates provide the solutions in increasing order, not necessarily in the order that they occur in the original list. That was not stated as a requirement, however.

Answer (score 2):

here is an answer based on selection of higher value from input list:

```
n_largest(_, 0, []).
n_largest(L, N, [M|Ms]) :-
    N > 0,
    select(M, L, L1), \+ (member(X, L1), X > M),
    N1 is N - 1,
    n_largest(L1, N1, Ms).
```

the key it's of course the join `select(M, L, L1), \+ (member(X, L1), X > M)` that yields a double result: the max M of current list L, and the list where M has been removed.